# SimpleInjector CrossWiring confusion

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, simple-injector

I've been looking through the Simple Injector documentation and thought I was doing things right regarding Crosswiring, but alas...

I have the following which fails to resolve my App through the `IServiceProvider`

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using SimpleInjector;
using SimpleInjector.Lifestyles;
using SimpleInjectorTesting;

Container container = new Container { Options = { DefaultScopedLifestyle =
    new AsyncScopedLifestyle()}};

using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information))
    .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) =>
    {
        container.RegisterSingleton<App>();

        services.AddSingleton<ISaySomethingService, SaySomethingService>();
        services.AddSimpleInjector(container);   
    })
    .Build();

host.Services.UseSimpleInjector(container);

container.Verify();

var app = host.Services.GetRequiredService<App>();
//var app = container.GetInstance<App>();
await app.Run();
```

If I switch to use the `container.GetInstance<App>()` call the it works fine, SI can resolve services registered from `IServiceCollection`.

If I set `options.AddLogging()` to SI, an `IServiceProvider` registered type can't receive ILogger even if I'm using `container.GetInstance<App>()`

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type App failed. The registered delegate for type ISaySomethingService threw an exception. Failed to resolve ISaySomethingService. ISaySomethingService is a cross-wired service, meaning that Simple Injector forwarded the request the framework's IServiceProvider in order to get an instance. The used Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider, however, failed with the following message: "Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'SimpleInjectorTesting.SaySomethingService'.". This error might indicate a misconfiguration of services in the framework's IServiceCollection.'

So I have this library that does a bunch of stuff using SI and leverages decorators, conditionals, etc that standard .NET DI makes difficult but I want this library to be usable by anyone who may not be using Simple Injector. I have an extension method to Register my framework and then another to use it which does the `container.Verify()` call to get the SI specific stuff tucked away. But then I can't resolve through `IServiceProvider` as per the code above. Is this even possible with SI and if so what am I missing?

Update:
This is my App class

```
public class App
{
    private readonly ISaySomethingService _saySomethingService;

    public App(ISaySomethingService saySomethingService)
    {
        _saySomethingService = saySomethingService;
    }

    public async Task Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_saySomethingService.Message());

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you registering `ISaySomethingService` in the `IServiceCollection` instead of registering it in Simple Injector?

Comment: I was testing out having things registered in both. Your questioning that makes me realise that's not likely going to be something I face with my library consumed in other projects, but even if I do `container.RegisterSingleton<ISaySomethingService, SaySomethingService>();` I still get `System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type 'SimpleInjectorTesting.App' has been registered.'` when I try to resolve App from IServiceProvider with `var app = host.Services.GetRequiredService<App>()`. Is that just not doable?

Comment: I just added the App class to the question

Comment: Cross wiring is a one-way process. The Simple Injector integration package ensures that the Simple Injector container will try to look up any missing dependency from the MS.DI container. But it's impossible to do this the other way around in an automated fashion. But also something you would only need sporadically. In general, your SI-resolved application components might reference framework components (resolved from MS.DI) but those framework components less likely need to depend on any app components.

Comment: Ok, so I have this CQRS pattern with other services I tend to use all wrapped nicely in my library and I'd like to inject IProcessCommand, IProcessQueries, IDateTimeService, etc in my consuming application that only uses IServiceCollection / IServiceProvider, which could be ASP.NET Core, basic console app or hosted console app. Surely that's supported? I had all that functioning in AutoFac originally

Comment: So when integrating SI with MS.DI, the advice is as follows: register all your application components in SI, and let its auto cross-wiring feature pull framework and third-party components from MS.DI. For instance, if your application depends on MS logging, HttpClientFactory, or DbContext pooling, those are features that are tightly coupled with the MS.DI infrastructure. Those must be configured in MS.DI, and SI will pull them in automatically for you if your application components depend on say `ILogger<T>`, `IHttpClientFactory`, or a `DbContext`.

Comment: Can you define what "my library" means in your context? Is this a reusable package that you ship through e.g. NuGet and is used by more solutions and code based you don't have control any control over, or is this a project that is part of a single solution?

Comment: Yes a nuget package. So I get the impression that if I'm using SimpleInjector for this in my lirbrary the only way to resolve these services is to resolve from the Container instance in the hosted application?

Comment: "I had all that functioning in AutoFac originally". That's because Autofac can be used as a replacement of the entire DI infrastructure, but that's not how SI works. To understand why, please read [this](https://blog.simpleinjector.org/2016/06/whats-wrong-with-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/).

Comment: I think I've got enough information to answer your question now.

Comment: Yes thanks Steven. A colleague who uses SimpleInjector alot suggested it was possible so that's obviously lead me down a path. I understand the difference now, I appreciate your time. I might ship two integration packages. The main reason I've been thinking about non AutoFac was to have the libraries run well on mobile devices using .NET MAUI. I was trying to use Scrutor with built in, but there's issues there so SimpleInjector seemed like the way forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to integration with an .NET Core or ASP.NET Core application, Simple Injector works very differently compared to for instance Autofac. This has to do with the design choices made by Microsoft and their incompatibility with Simple Injector's design. I discussed this in detail [here](https://blog.simpleinjector.org/2016/06/whats-wrong-with-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/) and [here](https://blog.simpleinjector.org/2016/07/working-around-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/).

But this is why choosing Autofac for your DI container in an ASP.NET Core application, Autofac ends up replacing the entire DI infrastructure, which means all application, framework, and third-party registrations will be made in Autofac.

When choosing Simple Injector, on the other hand, the Simple Injector container will run side-by-side with the original MS.DI container. This means that you, as an application developer, will register your application components as part of Simple Injector, while framework and third-party libraries that depend on the `IServiceCollection` abstraction, will effectively use MS.DI as their backing container.

The Simple Injector integration package for .NET Core, however, does allow a feature called "cross wiring" or "auto cross wiring", which allows the Simple Injector container to resolve services from the built-in MS.DI container to inject them into your Simple Injector-resolved application components. This feature is implemented using Simple Injector's *unresolved type resolution*. As there is no such feature in MS.DI, it's not possible to let MS.DI automatically callback into Simple Injector to fetch missing dependencies. You can always do this on a per-service basis by making an explicit registration to MS.DI though, e.g. `services.AddTransient<IService>(_ => container.GetInstance<IService>())`.

In the majority of cases, however, you shouldn't need to be able to 'cross wire' back from MS.DI to Simple Injector, because the dependency would typically go from application component towards framework (or third-party) abstraction; not the other way around.

But the fact that Simple Injector doesn't replace the built-in DI infrastructure (but run side-by-side) does have the consequence that adding registrations to the `IServiceCollection` doesn't add them to Simple Injector. And this means that if you have a third-party library (or self-built NuGet package) that integrated with `IServiceCollection`, this won't run as part of Simple Injector.

Under normal conditions this wouldn't be a problem, because its okay for framework and third-party components to be composed by MS.DI, especially because Simple Injector makes it easy to pull them in. You, as an application developer, would typically don't see the difference (although it's important to understand what to register where).

But your case is different, because you are building a reusable library with **application-specific** abstractions (and implementations) while you want to simplify registration for the application developers using these abstractions. Adding a `AddMyReusableLibrary(this IServiceCollection)` method to that library will work when the end application is completely relying on MS.DI or Autofac, but won't help when the application uses Simple Injector.

There are a few options here:

1. You build an extra NuGet package, say `MyReusableLibrary.SimpleInjector` that depends on both `MyReusableLibrary` and `SimpleInjector`, and adds an `AddMyReusableLibrary(this SimpleInjector.Container)` method, or
2. You simply document what registrations need to be made to Simple Injector. It will typically be a handful of registrations. This gives the application developer full control and knowledge about the made registrations, although, admittingly, does cause some more code in the application's Composition Root, and doesn't allow new features in vNext of your `MyReusableLibrary` to get automatically added.
3. You design your reusable library according to Mark Seemann's advice on [DI-friendly libraries](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/). Although, in your case that unlikely helps because your reusable library actually contains **application abstractions**. It is a reusable library as in -it is a NuGet package-, but in fact contains parts of the application's core design and domain.